# Displaying multiple columns in single carousel item with Bootstrap carousel

Tags: css, json, angular, bootstrap-4, angular6

So I am able to have four columns in single item at a time , but when I implement '**carousel**' class (4th div in html file) then the first two item displays fine. But in the last item as it should only have 2 columns with task name 9 and 10, instead task name **1** and **5** are also displayed there.

if I don't implement carousel class then data displays fine but carousel buttons stops working.

' I've already tried different solutions provided on stack overflow. '

here is my HTML file

```
    <!-- my tasks -->
<div class="row mt-3 mb-3">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <!-- carousel -->

        <div class="row mx-auto my-auto">
            <div id="myTaskDiv" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner w-100">
                    <!-- carousel item -->
                    <div class="carousel-item {{ i == 0 ? 'active' : '' }}" *ngFor="let chunkMyTask of productData ;let i =index;">
                        <!--widget-->
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" *ngFor="let myTask of chunkMyTask">
                            <div class="widget border">
                                <div class="widget-body">
                                {{myTask.name}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--widget end-->
                        </div>
                        <!-- carousel item end-->
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- carousel controls -->
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" role="button" href="#myTaskDiv" data-slide="prev">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-left fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" role="button" href="#myTaskDiv" data-slide="next">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
                <!-- carousel controls end-->
            </div>

            <!-- carousel end -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- my tasks end-->
```

then this below is my .ts file

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { task } from '../task';
import { TasksService } from '../tasks.service';
import { MyTaskServiceService } from 'src/app/dashboard/my-tasks/my-task-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-tasks',
  templateUrl: './my-tasks.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-tasks.component.css']

export class MyTasksComponent {
  title = 'Carousel';
  productData: any;

  private myTasks: any;
  private myTaskArray: any;
  constructor(private myTaskService: MyTaskServiceService) { }

 chunks(array, size) {
  let results :any;
  results = [];
  while (array.length) {
    results.push(array.splice(0, size));
    this.num=this.num+1;
  }
  return results;
}
ngOnInit() {
  this.myTaskService.get_New_Products().subscribe(
    data => {
        this.productData = this.chunks(data.json(), 4);
        console.log(this.productData);
    });


}
}
```

And at last this below is my json file:

```
[
{
    "taskType": "myTask",
    "name": "Task 1"
},
{
    "taskType": "myTask",
    "name": "Task 2"
},
{
    "taskType": "myTask",
    "name": "Task 3"
},
{
    "taskType": "myTask",
    "name": "Task 4"
},
{
    "taskType": "myTask",
    "name": "Task 5"
},
{
    "taskType": "myTask",
    "name": "Task 6"
},
{
    "taskType": "myTask",
    "name": "Task 7"
},
{
    "taskType": "myTask",
    "name": "Task 8"
},
{
    "taskType": "myTask",
    "name": "Task 9"
},
{
    "taskType": "myTask",
    "name": "Task 10"
}
```

]

Comment: Can you provide CSS  or create a snippet of your code. And don't remove `carousel` class it is mandatory to access bootstrap carousel default CSS.

Comment: There is no custom css in my code. But if I don't remove css class then if in my item there are only two columns then it appending tow columns by itself